# LINQ combined columns contain

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have three fields; first name, middle initial, and last name.  How would I do a LINQ query to check if:

```
x = query // i.e. john
y = first name + " " + middle initial + " " last name // i.e. john a smith

if (y.contains(x))

// return y
```

Comment: Huh? What is your question?

Comment: Well, that looks like you possibly want a `let` clause and a `where` clause. What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: Could you provide decent C# code?

Comment: This is just pseudo code!  It's obvious, I am trying to see if `x` exists in `y` where `y` equals the full name (comprised of three separate columns) and `x` is just a fragment...

Comment: It's not that obvious.

Comment: Basically, I need to create a calculated column in LINQ and see if my query is contained in the calculated column.  If so, return the results.  See the comment I posted on your answer for more details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that you want to check multiple members of an object using LINQ try this:

```
var items = listOfObjects.Where(t => (t.firstName + " " + t.middleInitial + " " +  t.lastName).Contains(x));
```

Comment: It's not quite this simple, I'm afraid.  Imagine a user searches for `john smith`.  It won't find `john smith` in `t.firstName` (which would just be `john`).